# vifm: How to format mtime column to display Year?

Tags: vifm

I'm quite new to vifm but I've been reading the [manual](https://vifm.info/) and browsing around. So far I've been able to do all I wanted to do with it, but I'm missing a piece.

I wanted to display the modification date as the "2nd column" (and in fact, I sort by that descending), but after seeing [this screenshot](https://vifm.info/screenshots/reicheltd-light.png), prompted by [this StackOverflow question/answer combo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42267782/vifm-show-date-time-in-filelist), I noticed my (same) `viewcolumns` doesn't produce the same output:

[image: vifm]

The `mtime` formatting is not showing the year.

Here's the (relevant) `vifmrc` block:

```
set viewcolumns=*{name}..,16{mtime}
set sort=-mtime
```

I've tried a few other alternatives but I think I need to tell something to mtime somewhere, and I'm usure where to look (searching for vifm is hard, as most results are either for `vi` (the editor) or just the keywords are too generic to find relevant results (or maybe I'm bad at searching).

Any ideas how to produce a day/month/year (in 2 digit format is fine) followed by HH:mm?

is the mtime command using some form of environment variable and therefore formatting it day/month hour:minute somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am very silly. I missed the `timefmt` piece of `vifmrc`.

```
" Format for displaying time in file list. For example:
" TIME_STAMP_FORMAT=%m/%d-%H:%M
" See man date or man strftime for details.
```

So I went ahead and changed it to:

`set timefmt=%d/%m/%y\ %H:%M`

And I'm using this `viewcolumns`:

`set viewcolumns=*{name}..,16{mtime}`

Output: 
[image: vifm showing correct date format]